# How to get nth root of a number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example

```
x ** 3 # => 125
```

Knowing that the result of applying `**` with an argument `3` to `x` is `125`, how can I get the value of `x`?
Is there some kind of built-in method for this? I have been looking at the [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html) module but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: You could search on Google also. Look here - https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/191287 and http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=20068

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `**` with `1/3`:

```
125 ** (1.0/3)
# => 4.999999999999999
```

Comment: what is the question? I didn't get.

Comment: Find the `x` that satisfying `x ** 3 == 125`.

Comment: So is there no way to get exact arbitrary-precision exponentiation in ruby?  It seems like a Rational to a Rational power should produce a Rational, not a float or BigDecimal...

Comment: for cube root you can use `Math.cbrt(x)`!

Comment: @MarkReed old question, and i dunno if this is new or what, but `Rational(2) ** Rational(4)`
outputs `(16/1)` (a rational)

Comment: Yeah, I see that the answer has just `125`; if it were `Rational(125)` it would return a `Rational`, even in 1.9.3. Thanks, @maxpleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an Nth root by raising to a fractional power.  For example, the 4th root of 625 is 5.

```
(BigDecimal(625)**(1.0/4.0)).to_f
# => 5.0
```

Note, the `.to_f` is added for readability in this answer only.  Don't cast it to a Float in your code unless you need to.  IMHO, BigDecimals are "better" than Floats in Ruby - Floats lose precision too easily and you won't get accurate results.  Case in point the accepted awnser above.  The cube root of 125 is not 4.99999(repeat).  It is 5.0 exactly.

Edit: the Ruby Class Rational seems to handle nth roots a little better.

```
2.3.3 :007 > 625.to_r ** 0.25
=> 5.0
```

But it still isn't as precise with a number that produces an irrational root.

```
2.3.3 :024 > (999.to_r ** 0.25) ** 4
=> 998.9999999999999
```

Close...but you should be able to get back to 999.0 exactly.  My Mac's calculator and excel can do it.  Main point - just be careful.  If precision is important, Ruby may not handle this exactly the way one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try as below :

```
irb(main):005:0> 125**(3**-1)
=> 5
irb(main):006:0> 125**(3**-1.0)
=> 4.999999999999999
irb(main):007:0>
```

**update**

```
C:\Users >ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: `125**(3**-1)` returns `4.999999999999999` on my system, what Ruby version are you running?

Comment: Interesting, seems to be OS dependent

Comment: This probably doesn't work if both the argument and result aren't whole Integers.

Comment: Me too @stefan.  Ruby 2.5.1 on Mac OS X (rvm)